# idp_metadata_parser.parse_remote OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: nested asn1 error

Tags: ruby, saml, onelogin

When i extract X509Certificate from a idp_metadata file, i can view and decode certificate.

But when i use parse_remote, it’s fail with this error
`OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: nested asn1 error`

Can you have a idea about that ?

Comment: Did you check, that the IdP meta data file is schema compliant with the SAML meta data schema?

Comment: Another StackOverflow question [Certificate to pem to certificate not working: nested asn1 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767262/certificate-to-pem-to-certificate-not-working-nested-asn1-error) demonstrates that you may need more information in addition to X.509 Certificate.