# Ruby on Rails and "Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to get RSA with:

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(private_key)
```

and return **OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error**
private_key its defined by reading a file.key and the string is:

```
"0\x82\x02\xC60@\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\x05\r030\e\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\x05\f0\x0E\x04\b\x02\x01\x00\x02\x81\x81\x00\xA4\x02\x02\x04\x000\x14\x06\b*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x03\a\x04\b0\x82\x02v\x02\x01\x000\x04\x82\x02\x80\xFE[J\x92\xED\xCB\xBA\xA5u*V\xBD\xF10\v\xDF\x9D\xF4\xEF\x99\xD63<x\xD7\x87\x82\x01\xE3\x99\xB6\xB7\xAE\x88J\x1C\xCFi\n\xCD\xCE?*\xCBPD\r\xAA+G\xFB\x180~2</\x9E\x8C\x87\xE6?\xEA\x8B\xB9@\xB1\xB0\xD6\x90H\xF2\xDC\xF5F$\xA4\xC3\xF9\xE4\xB3\xB9\x7F{*\xE0\"\x9C\x82\x82\f)T\x1C\x84\xE7\xEFQl\xC5\xCF^\x91\xC65\x88\x92\f\x19n\xC7y\xB4|\xA3`\xC0\x8C\xC1\x96S7Nf\xC5\xD0\r\xFA\xBFG\x15\xB1\x81\xF5p%\x12T2\x95\xFE2Z\xD7\xED\xE12\x01\a\xACN\xA6#\xBE\x94\xA1\x97'<\x9C\xB2\xD2\xBEI\xF1io\xBF\xD1\xE0\xB6\x1A\x10o\x15\xEB'F~\xAC\xC3eG\xBF\xF2\x84\x88\xD9\x1C\x0E\xED\x13s\x91jTnU\xCD\xB9[\x9C?\xB3\xDC\xAE\xD4\x16n\xAE?\xD0\x01\xB0\x16)SMd\xF2\x02q\xBB\xC5;\x83\x19+\x90\x18\x7F\xDC\xB3\xA4\xC4\x1Cs\xFA\x13\xA1\xA3;d\ekUT\x98/wd\x1E\x9Er\xD4\x02\xE6\xEBB'$\x14\xBF\b\xF3\xDC\xCFe,;\x97\x9C\xD3\x92\xC1\x00\x9F\xFDu#\xA4\x7F\r\x16D 1\xEA\f^\xD0\xC5\xB1\r'\xDC\x9D\xDF\xF7\xCE\xCE+{\x96^\xD1\x8C\b_\x12\xDC\xD8x9}\x05Rq\xB9\xCC\xFE\xFEvd\xB7\x108\xC8\xE1\xE5\xD4\xC4i\x9D\xDA(\x05[\xC0_t\xF5\e\x18\xBB\x1D\xEC\xAE\xC7\xE8\x8A(\x90w\xCF\xFEcl[\xC2\a3\xB2 ~^\xC4\x1D\x0F\xACl\x11M\xE4\xA1\xF2Y\x04o,\xAEl\xC1\x0F$\x13qSc\x99\x1A\xD2$|\xBC\xAB\x90\xE7\xF0\xF7f\xDF\xC8\xBF\x16;lA_\x85\xCA\x0F\x9B#~d\xF2\x9C\x13*\xA9=Jl\x81t\x85\x96*l\xA8(kt\xD4\x19\xB4\xB8\x01U7\xEC\xE9.#;\xA0\x0F\x03\x91\x04-\n/P\xDC\xCC\x1A\xA5\xDD\xDA\xE4\x1F\xF2\\\xF1\xCA\x97,E\"0\x93\xD7\xD9\xD1\x1F\x84G_C\xCC\xC23~\xBDC\xA7ab\xBD\xBC\x83\xCA\xB1\xE3\xE0\x8F ^\xC0\xDF~\xB5\xBAT\xE8\xDE\x8E\xFE\xC3\xE5\xCF\xEB\xAC\xE3|n\x8B\x0E&%\xCA\x8Dqk\xAD=\x86\x05\xD4\xD9+\xF4\xA6\xEE\x9E\xA3\x00d!\x95b\xEDuY\xAE\xE5jG0\x85\xDE\"\xADc\xACK\x833\xA5lP#\x00=G\xB3\xCE\xF6\xC0[\xD4\x99U\xD5\e:{\x100\x9B{\x95\x9C@ \xB3\x86\xC2@S\x15~p\xD8\x9B\x13\xF48[\xBE\b\e\x7F\xD7x)\x10\xD7\x1A\xDE\xF2\x9E\xA5X\x8A\x7FV\xF3\xEC\xDE\xB1\xC9\acl\x04B\x8F\xD3c\x80\xE1\x16BI\xED\xAA}"
```

this is the base64 string.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
MIICxjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIAgEAAoGBAKQC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\nvggbf9d4KRDXGt7ynqVYin9W8+zesckHY2wEQo/TY4DhFkJJ7ap9\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

I don't know where is the formatting problem.

Comment: That gigantic string isn't really informative at all. Why don't you have a proper PBKDF key string?

Comment: Do you mean the base64 string?

Comment: That's how they're normally stored and loaded. This looks like a binary raw key, not sure that works. It should have a header like `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.

Comment: i tried both ways, with the string i posted avobe and the base64 string with begin and end tags, the error persist.

Comment: I don't know what that is but it's not an RSA private key. `openssl asn1parse -in input.key` does seem to decode it and shows `des-ede3-cbc` as the payload.

Comment: Also see [Getting OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError nested asn1 error on Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24263835/608639), [Certificate to pem to certificate not working: nested asn1 error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41767262/608639), [Ruby OpenSSL nested asn1 error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27645249/608639), [Ruby Error reading in Certificate File with OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8720981/608639).

Comment: You should try manually adding newlines at 72 characters in the key's body. Early standards required them.

Comment: I already read those articles, in openssl i used: **openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key -passin pass:xxxxxxxx >private_key.pem**. do you know how to do this on ruby?

Comment: Have you tried gsubbing out the newlines?